# How to store a database intensive page into cache from a background process in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, backgroundworker

In my website i have a database intensive page which i cache for 5 mins. But still the performance is hit when the cache expires and the page has to be rendered freshly. I was thinking why not compute the page from a background process(like workling) once in 5 mins and store it in the cache and let the user request be serve from the cache everytime. And as a result no user have to wait for this page to be rendered.

Is there a efficient way to do it?
Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend simply making a call to your web-server for the page from your background-job or cron job. Then you let your entire Rails stack handle the call. You could create a cron job to do this every 4-5 minutes and pass a parameter to the page to have it force a cache refresh, for example:

```
complex/page?force=true
```

Your controller/action/model would then check for the presence of this parameter. If force was present the page would not use the cached version, but would re-create the cache instead.

Comment: would be helpful if u could ans this question too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409824/how-to-write-a-partial-into-a-cache-from-a-back-ground-process-and-read-the-parti

Comment: Could you provide a code example of how you would call the web server for page "complex/page?force=true" from a background/cron job?

Comment: There are many HTTP libraries that allow you to do this. Ruby has the built in `Net::HTTP` library, but you could also use a command line tool like `curl`. If you want a more detailed answer I would recommend posting another question.